# Spark "Run SQL on files directly" fails

Tags: python, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, localstack

[Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html#run-sql-on-files-directly) suggests I can run SQL directly on files in PySpark with syntax like this:

```
df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM parquet.`examples/src/main/resources/users.parquet`")
```

I have some Delta format data sitting in an AWS S3 bucket (well, currently a fake S3 bucket in LocalStack). I'm trying to query it using this approach. The bucket looks like this:

```
$ awslocal s3 ls s3://data-lake/data/
                       PRE _delta_log/
2023-06-07 16:55:33        903 part-00000-923a2eea-e2fe-468e-b2b9-a85206858ddb-c000.snappy.parquet
2023-06-07 16:55:33        914 part-00001-a6ceac4f-d7ea-44e9-bce9-d7fe0c103e35-c000.snappy.parquet
```

And while the following works just fine:

```
df = spark.read.format("delta").load("s3://data-lake/data")
```

The syntax I'm trying to query it with using SQL as follows fails:

```
df = spark.sql("select * from delta.`s3://data-lake/data`")
```

(I've also tried with the path directly to a file rather than just the containing directory with not difference).

The data is written via the following simple Scala Spark code:

```
val ds = Seq(
  Foo("a", Bar(1, 2)),
  // etc
).toDS()

ds
  .write
  .format("delta")
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .save("s3://data-lake/data")
```

The error I am getting when I try and query this is as follows, edited a bit for brevity:

```
Py4JError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_178/100492152.py in <module>

---> 11 df = spark.sql("select * from delta.`s3://data-lake/data`")

<snip>

py4j.Py4JException: Method sql([class java.lang.String, class java.util.HashMap]) does not exist
```

Feels like a weird thing in the plumbing rather than a syntax error on my part (not least because if I try the same approach in Scala it works OK).

- Python 3.7.16
- PySpark 3.4.0
- Running from a Jupyter notebook against a LocalStack container based on the `emr-serverless/spark/emr-6.10.0:latest` image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, it looks like a mismatch between the versions of PySpark and the underlying Spark. The error is that py4j is not able to invoke the `SparkSession::sql()` method that takes both a parameterised query and a map of parameter names with their values:

```
py4j.Py4JException: Method sql([class java.lang.String, class java.util.HashMap]) does not exist
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That particular overload was added in Spark 3.4.0 and PySpark 3.4.0 always makes use of it, no matter if the query is parameterised or not:

```py
...
try:
   litArgs = {k: _to_java_column(lit(v)) for k, v in (args or {}).items()}
   return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery, litArgs), self)
...
```

Make sure that Spark's home directory is properly configured in the notebook environment and that PySpark is not using an older Spark version.

---

Indeed, checking what version is [the software](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-6100-release.html) included in `emr-6.10.0` proves my theory correct:

[image: emr-6.10.0 versions]

Downgrade your PySpark to version 3.3.1.

Comment: Ah that is awesome sleuthing just outside my knowledge levels to have done independently. Thank you so, so much!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've mistaken the documentation.

It says you can read directly from a **file**.

> Delta Lake is an open source file protocol that stores data in Parquet files

I suggest trying:

```py
df = spark.sql("select * from parquet.`s3://data-lake/data/part-00000-923a2eea-e2fe-468e-b2b9-a85206858ddb-c000.snappy.parquet`")
```

But since **delta folders** are not file formats, I do not see why `select * from delta` would ever work.

The reason why `df = spark.read.format("delta").load("s3://data-lake/data")` works is because you can **load** from a folder.

Comment: The OP explicitly states that it works in Scala: "Feels like a weird thing in the plumbing rather than a syntax error on my part **(not least because if I try the same approach in Scala it works OK)**."

Comment: There is no proof and the question has been edited since I posted my answer.

Comment: The question has not been edited since asked.

Comment: Oh... My bad then, I completely missed the Scala part, and assumed it was an edit.